# Print data of UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid version v3.2.9. My goal is to print the data which is already rendered in UI.
My table is made up of div by using angular ui grid.
My approach is:-

Opening a new window in which I am appending the HTML of the grid.
and then calling window.print() method to print all the content of the newly opened window.

But the problem here is if there are so many records in my grid then vertical scroll is coming in my newly opened window and when I am calling window.print() method then it only prints the visible area of the window not all the content of the window.
Here is my pseudo code:-

```
function print(id){
  var print = document.getElementById(id);  
  var w = window.open("", "");  
  var headContent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].outerHTML;  
  var writeMe = ('<html><body><head>' + headContent + '</head>');  
  writeMe += (print.outerHTML);  
  writeMe += ('</body></html>');  
  w.document.write(writeMe);  
  w.document.close();  
  w.focus();
  w.setTimeout(function(){
    w.print();
    w.close();
  }, 1000);  
}
```

So, anyone can please suggest that what could I improve in my code to print the content of the entire window.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: yet it do not understable to me can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add on id on row or grid as printable

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    #printable { display: none; }

    @media print
    {
        #non-printable { display: none; }
        #printable { display: block; }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="non-printable">
        Your normal page contents
    </div>

    <div id="printable">
        Printer version
    </div>
</body>
```

logic for visibleArea

```
function visibleArea(){
     var pwidth = $(window).width();
     var pheight = $(window).height();
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();       
       $("h1").html("total visible area is from:"+ top +" to "+ (pheight + top) +"px"); // add printable id and rest of non-printable

}
```

if you have id so can pass with id like

```
  function printpage(){
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printReport= document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printReport;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the media query for such problems

```
@media only print {
   #idOfYourDiv {
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     overflow: visible;
   }
}
```

This CSS will be applied for print command only, so `overflow : visible` will solve your problem